# Getting weekdays and dates for a week

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am working on an app where I need to create a weekly calendar. For this I will need days and dates of current week(Sun Sep30, Mon Oct 1, Tue Oct2 etc.). Can someone please guide me how to achieve this?

Regards
Pankaj

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple function which extracts date for all the days in this week, staring from Sunday this week to Saturday,

```
func formattedDaysInThisWeek() -> [String] {
    // create calendar
    let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!

    // today's date
    let today = NSDate()
    let todayComponent = calendar.components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: today)

    // range of dates in this week
    let thisWeekDateRange = calendar.rangeOfUnit(.Day, inUnit:.WeekOfMonth, forDate:today)

    // date interval from today to beginning of week
    let dayInterval = thisWeekDateRange.location - todayComponent.day

    // date for beginning day of this week, ie. this week's Sunday's date
    let beginningOfWeek = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: dayInterval, toDate: today, options: .MatchNextTime)

    var formattedDays: [String] = []

    for i in 0 ..< thisWeekDateRange.length {
        let date = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: i, toDate: beginningOfWeek!, options: .MatchNextTime)!
        formattedDays.append(formatDate(date))
    }

    return formattedDays
}

func formatDate(date: NSDate) -> String {
    let format = "EEE MMMdd"
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = format
    return formatter.stringFromDate(date)
}
```

If you call method **formattedDaysInThisWeek()**, the output is like this,

```
["Sun Oct11", "Mon Oct12", "Tue Oct13", "Wed Oct14", "Thu Oct15", "Fri Oct16", "Sat Oct17"]
```

Comment: @Sandeep, how we can get first date of week as moday, instead of sunday?

Comment: @Ranjit calendar.firstWeekday = 2;  /* 1 == Sunday and 7 == Saturday */

Answer (score 2):

Do you just need it for this week? If so, here's some code that you should be able to use:

```
- (NSString *)stringOfDatesOfThisWeek {
    NSArray *datesOfThisWeek = [self dateOfTheWeek:[NSDate date]];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d"];

    NSMutableString *dateStringForThisWeek = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[formatter stringFromDate:[datesOfThisWeek firstObject]]];
    for (int i = 1; i < datesOfThisWeek.count; i++) {
        [dateString appendFormat:@", %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[datesOfThisWeek objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }
}

- (NSArray *)datesOfTheWeek:(NSDate *)todaysDate {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSInteger weekNumber =  [[calendar components: NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:todaysDate] week];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *comp = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:todaysDate];
    [comp setWeek:weekNumber];  //Week number.

    NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        [comp setWeekday:1]; //First day of the week. Change it to 7 to get the last date of the week
        NSDate *resultDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comp];
        [dates addObject:resultDate];
    }

    return dates;
}
```

and after typing all of that without Xcode, I realized that this question was asked about Swift. I'm leaving it in case someone wants an Objective-C answer and stumbles across this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, to get expected date format you can use `NSDateFormatter` with following formatter:

`NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat:@"EEEE, MMM d";
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);`

You can also set locale for date formatter to get weekdays in specified language:

`[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"]];`

For more details please refer to [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

Updated Objective - c Code of @fennelouski :

```
- (NSString *)stringOfDatesOfThisWeek {
NSArray *datesOfThisWeek = [self datesOfTheWeek:[NSDate date]];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d"];

NSMutableString *dateStringForThisWeek = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[formatter stringFromDate:[datesOfThisWeek firstObject]]];
for (int i = 1; i < datesOfThisWeek.count; i++) {
    [dateStringForThisWeek appendFormat:@", %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[datesOfThisWeek objectAtIndex:i]]];
}
return dateStringForThisWeek;
}

- (NSArray *) datesOfTheWeek:(NSDate *)todaysDate {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSInteger weekNumber =  [[calendar components: NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth fromDate:todaysDate] weekOfMonth];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

    NSDateComponents *comp = [gregorian components:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:todaysDate];
    [comp setWeekOfMonth:weekNumber];  //Week number.

    NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        [comp setWeekday:1]; //First day of the week. Change it to 7 to get the last date of the week
        NSDate *resultDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comp];
        [dates addObject:resultDate];
    }

    return dates;
}
```